# useReducer : Unknown trigger of dispatch function causing action.<property> not defined error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

The following is my reducer function :

```js
const reducer = (state, action) => {
    let newState;
    switch (action.type) {
        case "load-start":
            newState = { ...state, loading: true };
        case "load-end":
            newState = { ...state, loading: false };
        case "data-fetch":
            newState = {
                ...state,
                more: action.more,
                data: [...state.data, ...action.data],
                iter: action.iter || state.iter + 1,
            };

        default:
            newState = state;
    }

    return newState;
};
```

And here's the dispatch function call in the useEffect() hook

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async (iter) => {
        const [posts, func_more] = await GetPosts(iter);
        let action = {
            type: "data-fetch",
            data: posts,
            more: func_more,
        };
        dispatch(action);
    };
    
    fetchData(state.iter).catch((err) => console.error(err));
}, [])
```

I tried logging the values of action.data and other variables but nothing helped. It's always undefined. I tried adding an "id" field in the action object to trace the dispatch call which triggers this (I have a few other calls with the same type) but that field was also undefined when it reached the reducer function.

And the stack trace always points back to the line where the useReducer() hook is called :

```js
// action.data is undefined
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initial_state);
                                     ^
```

which doesn't help either.

Any leads/corrections? Thank you.

Comment: is it `action.iter` in reducer function? You are no passing that when you dispatch.

Answer (score 0):

It was actually an issue with the reducer function. Instead of returning the newState outside the switch-case statement, returning each of them in their own case block worked.

Now it looks something like this :

```js
const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "load-start":
            return { ...state, loading: true };
        case "load-end":
            return { ...state, loading: false };
        case "data-fetch":
            return {
                ...state,
                more: action.more,
                data: [...state.data, ...action.data],
                iter: state.iter + 1,
            };
        case "data-cache":
            return {
                ...state,
                more: action.more,
                data: action.data,
                iter: action.iter,
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```